# Submitting bootstrap form via Ajax passes wrong parameters

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I've built a data entry page using Bootstrap and I'm trying to process it via Ajax/jQuery. When I click the Submit button, though by tracing, I can see my ajax method is called, what gets sent isn't the right thing at all.

Here's an excerpt of the HTML, showing only one text control plus the button. The real page has a lot more controls:

```
<form role="form" id="addform" name="addform" class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-form-label col-md-offset-1 col-md-1" for="actiontitle">Action title</label>
        <div class="col-md-9">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="actiontitle" name="actiontitle" placeholder="Action title" required>
        </div>
        <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
    </div>
        <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <button type="submit" "btn btn-default" id="submit" name="submit">Submit</button>
        </div>
    </div>      
</form>
```

The Ready function includes this code:

```
$('#addform').submit(function(event){
    saveAction();
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Here's the key piece of the saveAction function. There's code above this that populates the fnargs variable:

```
    $.ajax({
        url: 'retrievedata.php',
        type: "POST",
        async:false,
        data: {"functionname":"getdata", "arguments":fnargs},
        dataType: "JSON",
        success: function (obj) {
            alert('Your action has been submitted and will be reviewed. Thanks for adding to Acts of Conscience');
            $('addform').each(function(){
                this.reset;
            }); 
        },
        error: function(textStatus, errorThrown) {
             success = false;
             alert('We were unable to add your action. Please try again.');
        }
    })
```

When I click the button, what gets sent is something like this:

```
http://www.XXXXXX.com/addacts.php?actiontitle=The+data+I+typed+in&submit=
```

That is, it calls the same page rather than the page specified in the Ajax call.

Comment: Considering you added `event.preventDefault();` and the page still redirects to that URL, you probably have some javascript errors. What does the console say?

Comment: I'm not super experienced with javascript, but maybe you need to move the event.preventDefault(); so that it comes before the call to saveAction()

Comment: @LuchaLauraHardie, I've tried it both ways. It doesn't make a difference.

Comment: @eeetee, the only message that appears in the console is this: Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user’s experience. For more help http://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/

Comment: I was able to get rid of the XMLHttpRequest message by changing the ajax calling to asynchronous. That seems to have resolved the immediate problem and I'm getting the right call. Off to find out why that's not working.